Nondeterminism vs. Stochasticity
Let's assume I have the following automaton:

If this is a non-deterministic automaton, I can never be sure
that the transition $q_0 \to q_1$ has taken place.
However, if the edges had weights,
and I would choose an edge with a probability
that is proportional to its weight,
I would be confident that, after many steps,
there is negligible chance of transition $q_0 \to q_1$
not having taken place yet.
If I were to simulate this automaton using a computer,
I would make a probabilistic choice between the transitions.
However, this effectively changes my model,
from non-deterministic to stochastic.
The question is,
how can one perfectly simulate non-determinism with a computer?

We don't need to simulate it.
An automaton is a model of a system's behavior.
For instance, a system that conforms to this model is a simple application with one button that can be pushed. The button is blue initially. When pushed, the button may remain blue, or it may turn green. Once green, when pushed, the button remains green forever. The states model the button's color.
If this is all we know about the system, the model is perfect like this. The system doesn't "simulate" the model. The model doesn't need to be "simulated". The model simply expresses what we know about the system.
But, but, but ... systems are deterministic, right? No, they're not. A "system" is an abstraction, a set of things exhibiting certain behavior. A model, such as an automaton, simply specifies behavior, and that specification may or may not be deterministic, depending on whether the behavior is deterministic, at the level of detail we're interested in describing.
Surely, if we have a concrete implementation of this system, we can peek into its inner workings and try to find out whether the way in which it changes color is deterministic at some level. We may find that it is determined by a some deterministic mechanism that, let's say, causes the color to flip after exactly 8 times of trying. We may find it flips a coin to decide. We may find it looks at a weather app and flips the color only if the temperature listed for Toledo (OH) is a prime number. We may find all sorts of things, and we may then be able to create a more specific model for the system that describes its workings in more detail. Maybe that model will have weights; maybe not. That model, too, will be an abstraction of the real implementation, and that model, too, may be deterministic, nondeterministic, stochastic, or something else, depending on what information about the system's behavior we have and wish to include. We then have a different, less general system model: fewer actual systems will conform to it. Whether we are interested in having such a more specific system model depends on what we're trying to do.
It is important to realize that the automata and Turing machines you encounter in computer science are not actual machines. They are not physical things or phenomena. They are abstract descriptions of potential system behavior, and as such it is perfectly natural for them to be nondeterministic: we often don't know what a system is going to do, and we need to be able to specify systems for which that is the case.
